Animated movie with the protagonist travelling through East Asia at the beginning of 20th century
I had seen this movie once on TV, it was adventures of (some person's name).
The movie is set in 1910-1930s era. The story followed a guy getting involved with the Chinese triads. Starts with him in china, he then goes to Siberia from Mongolia. He meets the Russians there. The hero had black hair and was more Chinese in look. I think he was a spy or something.
This movie is not TinTin. I also think the movie may not be in English. It had English subs as I recollect. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me find this movie.

It definitely sounds like you are looking for "Corto Maltese in Siberia"
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259134/
The movie is available on YouTube, check out them at http://madmonarchist.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/little-diversion-corto-maltese-in.html

You might want to explain why you think that is the searched movie and in which way it fits to the details from the question.
